# NFC data transfer on iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, transfer, data-transfer

Is it possible to transfer data between two iPhones using NFC? I'm working on an app that aims to exchange specific strings between two phones and would preferably use NFC. (If so, would it work for iPhone - Android connection?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Answer is NO.

So far apple has only allowed to read data. We cannot send any data between two iPhones or between an iPhone and a Android Device.

Comment: if someone came across this, know that if your iphone was jailbroken, you could do all sorts of nfc related stuff with a tweak called "NFCWriter", and because of the root access, you could trivially write your own code if you don't wanna pay for the tweak, or don't trust people.

Answer (score 0):

iOS11 seems to offer the potential to read NFC data so one-way traffic between Android and iOS appears possible.